# Unable to compile React Native Share Extension iOS 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

When upgrading to iOS 12.5, I am getting the compile error that: "Application extensions and any libraries they link to must be built with the `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` build setting set to YES."

However, I am explicitly setting it to false in my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Because this is required as a work-around for another [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25792#issuecomment-517295859).

If I set `config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'YES'`, then I get even more issues.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the 'Podfile' file,just set the "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" to Yes in Building Settings,it works for me.
This address maybe help you more. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405#issuecomment-779382959

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are you using an app extension? I'm using an iOS Share Extension written in React Native and need to have App-Extension-Safe API set to False in Build Setting, so not sure this really solves the issue

Comment: Yes,I'm using the app extension with React Native.And it looks like no effect set "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" to Yes, you can have a try.